# Web JavaScript app unable to find resources

Tags: javascript, web-services, amazon-ec2

A developer set up for me an online JavaScript app that is hosted on an **AWS EC2** instance. It has been operating fine until a few hours ago when suddenly navigating to the website produces a blank page.

I expose the source, and it appears that the HTML is trying to load a JavaScript app (see [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWwFG.png)), and when I look at the Web Inspector console, it seems that certain resources are not being found ([screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmOr4.png)). Strangely enough, I can't find these paths myself (except for app.js.map)

I have very limited knowledge about how web servers are run or how JavaScript works, but I do have some familiarity with AWS, and I have full access to the EC2 instance.

Considering nothing was intentionally or manually changed, I am guessing there must be some service that has stopped working.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further?

[image: Screenshot 1 - source]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a rather painful journey: `nginx` was dead.